# Why I getting error like "string indexing out of range" in 1st code and why not in the 2nd code by just changing the substring

Tags: python-3.x

Why the first code is giving error like this "string indexing out of range" but not the second code just by changing the sub_string
Describe it briefly
    1st code:-

```
a=rem=0
b=1
c=2
string = 'ABCDCDC'
sub_string = 'CDC'
for i in range(0,7):
    if (sub_string[0] == string[a] and           
sub_string[1] == string[b] and            
 sub_string[2] == string[c]):
        rem += 1
a += 1
b += 1
c += 1
print(rem)

2nd code:-

a=rem=0
b=1
c=2
string = 'ABCDCDC'
sub_string = 'ABC'
for i in range(0,7):
    if (sub_string[0] == string[a] and           
sub_string[1] == string[b] and            
sub_string[2] == string[c]):
        rem += 1
a += 1
b += 1
c += 1
print(rem)
```